# Git-SVN: How to configure git to ignore SVN URL in SHA1 computation

Tags: git, git-svn

Following is my SVN server setup where development team is on serverA which is being mirrored on ServerB, now thegitweb is pulling latest information from SVN ServerB which means SHA1 are different from what we see in the history.

```
SVN ServerA --- Mirror ---> SVN ServerB
     |                           |                          
     |                           |
  Development                  GitWeb 
(Using git-svn)
```

Is there anyway I can keep SHA1 in development and GitWeb in sync? I have tried svn-remote config rewriteRoot= SVN ServerA but it didn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The ID of a git commit is defined as the hash of the commit object, which includes the commit message. There is no way* to change the commit message without changing the commit ID.

If there is some way to entirely remove the SVN URL from the commit message, that might work. But I suspect that would break `git-svn`.

*: Short of finding a SHA1 collision, which is utterly infeasible

Comment: I am aware this is not possible in out of box git, and that's why I am looking for some hack or workaround here.